# Unread notification badge for Notification Center

Tags: macos, dock, notifications

Is there any way (application?) to display some sort of notification that there are unread items in Notification Center?

It could be just a badge on the icon, or the icon highlight, just anything that could omit opening the notification center for this.

I know that pretty much all the application have red badges on their icons, but when the dock is hidden it makes the same problem. I cannot see with a simple glance on the screen that some notifications (e.g. in some messenger apps) appeared. I always should reveal the dock to see this.

**Update:**

Well, I investigated everything myself. It seems there is simply no API for accessing notifications - so no 3rd party app is possible. It seems reasonable for security reasons.

The only way is to wait when Apple changes anything.

Comment: Can you please clarify what version of macOS you have installed?

Comment: it was el captain, but i upgraded to sierra.

Comment: To https://www.apple.com/feedback/ we must go.